# Probability that matrix is positive definite

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, positive-definite

> Given is the $2\times 2$ matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & y\\ y & x_2\end{pmatrix}$$ What's the probability that this matrix is positive definite for $x_1,x_2,y \in (-1,1)$ uniformly distributed?

---

I'm using the Eigenvalues to determine the definiteness.
$$(x_1-\lambda)(x_2-\lambda)-y^2 \overset{!}{>} 0\Longrightarrow y\in (-1,1)\wedge x_1>\lambda \wedge x_2>\frac{y^2}{x_1-\lambda}+\lambda$$

And now I want to find the CDF of this problem, but I'm not sure how to do it for 3 variables.

Maybe $\int_{-1}^{x_2} \int_{-1}^{x_1} \int_{-1}^y \frac{1}{1-(-1)} du\, dv\, dw$?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What does "continuously distributed" mean? Did you mean uniformly distributed?

Comment: @Iisyarus Oh yes. Sorry for the confusion, in my language it means continuously distributed. Fixed

Comment: Use Sylvester's criterion.

Matrix is positively defined if all determinants of upper-left corner submatrices are positive.

Therefore we need $x_{1} > 0 $ and det > 0.

So You need to find probability that function of three random variables is positive. I'm not probability spec so 

By the way, I think that exercise would be much harder if we dont assume that we have the same guys on counter-diagonal.

Comment: Being positive definite is the same as saying that the smallest eigenvalue is positive. In random matrix theory, you will find people who study the distribution of these eigenvalues.

Comment: @MaciejFicek Thanks for the tip with Sylvester criterion. So I got $y\in (-1,1), x_1\in (0,1), x_2\in (y^2/x_1,1)$. Much easier. Do you have any idea on how to find the CDF? I never did it with more than 1 random variable so I'm not sure. If I do it with the 3 integrals, I get... $\int_{y^2/x_1}^{x_2} \int_{0}^{x_1} \int_{-1}^y 1/2\, du\, dv\, dw = (-1/2)(y+1)(y^2+x_1x_2)$

Comment: @Quotenbanane Which random variable are you trying to compute the CDF of?  It isn’t clear from your question.  Keep in mind there are two eigenvalues.

Comment: @MaciejFicek I worked out (with Greg Martin) the details of a closely related distribution here: https://msp.org/ant/2008/2-8/p05.xhtml.  You’re right that the general non-symmetric case isn’t very pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the matrix $A$ is symmetric, its eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are real. From the properties of trace and determinant we have that $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = x_1 + x_2$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = x_1x_2 - y^2$. Therefore, $A$ is positive definite if and only if $x_1 + x_2 > 0$ and $x_1x_2 > y^2$. This means that $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$ and the set of points $(x_1, x_2, y)\in[-1, 1]^3$ corresponding to positive definite matrices is symmetric in the $y=0$ plane. Therefore, if we denote the volume between the surfaces $y=0$ and $y=\sqrt{x_1x_2}$ over the square $x_1,x_2\in[0,1]^2$ by $V$ then the probability that $A$ is positive definite is $\frac{V}{4}$. Finally, we compute

$$
\begin{align}
V=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x_1x_2}dx_1dx_2 = \left[\int_0^1\sqrt{x}dx\right]^2 = \frac49
\end{align}
$$

and conclude that the probability that $A$ is positive definite is $\frac19$.

Comment: I got the same $\frac19$ in a slightly different way. Where does the $V/4$ come from? Are you considering the half of the cube above $y = 0$ and then using symmetry?

Comment: Thanks for confirming using a different approach! Yes, I used the symmetry in the $y=0$ plane together with the requirement that $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$. Specifically, the $[-1,1]^3$ cube consists of eight unit cubes. Six of those are ruled out by $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$. Each of the two remaining ones contains a copy of the set whose volume we computed as $V$. Therefore, the probability is $\frac{2V}{8} = \frac{V}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I computed $2V$ and then divided by $2^3 = 8$.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Thank you for your answer! But I do not understand why we can assume that $y=0$ what's the idea behind it?

Comment: @Quotenbanane Not Adam. Because $y=0$ acts as a "mirror". Take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/a8tyrErWdr0) video.

Comment: Exactly. The figure defined as $\{(x_1, x_2, y) | y^2=x_1x_2\}$ is symmetric in the surface $y=0$. Therefore, instead of computing its volume directly we can compute the volume of the upper half (i.e. the part with $y>0$) and multiply the result by $2$.

Comment: Thank you guys for the great explanation.